# R: Possible to add summarise filed in dcast?

Tags: r, dplyr, tidyr, reshape2

R: Possible to add summarise filed in dcast?
User vs Number of order by month. and in between yearly summary add in it.

Check attached screenshot(excel's) for expected result.

```
User            Order_date          

a               02-01-2017          
b               02-02-2017          
a               02-08-2017          
c               02-05-2017          
a               02-08-2017          
s               02-06-2017          
c               02-03-2017          
s               02-04-2017          
b               02-06-2017          
c               02-11-2017          
a               02-11-2017          
s               02-11-2017          
c               02-01-2018          
s               02-01-2018          
b               02-02-2018          
b               02-10-2018
```

Try to generate report but not displayed summary values which is displayed in excel,
Please check the code and attached screenshot.

```
library(data.table)
library(lubridate)

df$start_year_month <- format(df$Month_Due, "%Y-%m")
#dcast(setDT(df), user ~ factor(start_year_month, levels = 1:12), sum, drop = FALSE)

datatable(dcast(df, user ~ start_year_month), filter = 'top',fun.aggregate =  ???? )
```

[Click here for Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NDhyq.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can first count for each month, the number of different users by doing:

```r
library(tidyr)
library(dplyr)
library(lubridate)
df <- df %>% mutate(Order_date = dmy(Order_date)) # Format the date from the reproducible example

DF <- df %>% arrange(Order_date) %>% mutate(months = format(Order_date, "%b_%Y")) %>%
  mutate(months = factor(months, unique(months))) %>%
  group_by(months, User) %>% count() 

# A tibble: 15 x 3
# Groups:   months, User [15]
   months   User      n
   <fct>    <chr> <int>
 1 Jan_2017 a         1
 2 Feb_2017 b         1
 3 Mar_2017 c         1
 4 Apr_2017 s         1
 5 May_2017 c         1
 6 Jun_2017 b         1
 7 Jun_2017 s         1
 8 Aug_2017 a         2
 9 Nov_2017 a         1
10 Nov_2017 c         1
11 Nov_2017 s         1
12 Jan_2018 c         1
13 Jan_2018 s         1
14 Feb_2018 b         1
15 Oct_2018 b         1
```

Then, you can create second dataframe with the count per Year:

```r
DF_Year <- df %>% arrange(Order_date) %>% mutate(months = paste(format(Order_date, "%Y"),"_Total",sep = "")) %>%
  mutate(months = factor(months, unique(months))) %>%
  group_by(months, User) %>% count() 

# A tibble: 7 x 3
# Groups:   months, User [7]
  months User      n
  <fct>  <chr> <int>
1 2017   a         4
2 2017   b         2
3 2017   c         3
4 2017   s         3
5 2018   b         2
6 2018   c         1
7 2018   s         1
```

You can bind both dataframe :

```r
DF_ALL <- bind_rows(DF, DF_Year)
```

Finally, you can pivot your dataframe into a larger format and order columns based on the year:

```r
DF_Final <- DF_ALL %>% pivot_wider(names_from = months, values_from = n) %>%
  select(contains("2017"),contains("2018")) 

# A tibble: 4 x 14
# Groups:   User [4]
  User  Jan_2017 Feb_2017 Mar_2017 Apr_2017 May_2017 Jun_2017 Aug_2017 Nov_2017 `2017_Total` Jan_2018 Feb_2018 Oct_2018
  <chr>    <int>    <int>    <int>    <int>    <int>    <int>    <int>    <int>        <int>    <int>    <int>    <int>
1 a            1       NA       NA       NA       NA       NA        2        1            4       NA       NA       NA
2 b           NA        1       NA       NA       NA        1       NA       NA            2       NA        1        1
3 c           NA       NA        1       NA        1       NA       NA        1            3        1       NA       NA
4 s           NA       NA       NA        1       NA        1       NA        1            3        1       NA       NA
# … with 1 more variable: `2018_Total` <int>
```

Does it answer your question ?

---

**Reproducible example**

```r
structure(list(User = c("a", "b", "a", "c", "a", "s", "c", "s", 
"b", "c", "a", "s", "c", "s", "b", "b"), Order_date = structure(c(17168, 
17199, 17380, 17288, 17380, 17319, 17227, 17258, 17319, 17472, 
17472, 17472, 17533, 17533, 17564, 17806), class = "Date")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-16L))
```

Comment: thank you so much, its working but i want to plot this as report and in that date is dynamic so not any fix year value in report. is there any other way that use year as dynamic: `DF_Final <- DF_ALL %>% pivot_wider(names_from = months, values_from = n) %>%
  select(contains("2017"),contains("2018"))`

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand your question. What do you mean by print as a report ? Like a table image ? or an actual plot with points, lines, bargraph ...?

Comment: it's R Dashboard where select one reference date from that date get data and based on that it displaying result like displayed in Attached screen shot.

Comment: Can we do this using dcast?

Comment: Sorry, I'm not familiar with R dashboard. I will let my answer if someone can use it in order to build a better answer and then I will delete it.